# Blender 2.91 convert to Grease pencil and preserve only outlines

Tags: cycles-render-engine, grease-pencil, 2d, outliner, tools

I am pretty new to Blender and what i want to do is to convert my entire mesh to grease pencil.

When i do this it shows all the edges and vertices with it i want to only keep the outline of the object and selected lines if i try to delete or dissolve edges or vertices it deletes unwanted segments and leaving holes.

Like in the image i provided how can i keep only the outline (i have tried Sculpt mode with removing thickness however in more complex meshes its very tedious).

[image]

Like i said i am very new to Blender and appreciate the help.

[image]

I am using Blender 2.91 on a Mac.

Or can anyone tell me how to achieve this kind of render with an animated look (anime mange and such) and explain how to render it my final output would be frames (for frame by frame animation).

And another question when i try to render with Cycles and choose freestyle the lines comes all jagged how do i solve this?

EDIT

I want something like this only outlines.

[image]

Kindest regards.

Comment: Hello, could you show an example of what you want the effect to look like ?

Comment: I want to preserve only the outline and remove all the vertices and edges i have updated my question.